# Sed | Variable containing regex causes invalid reference error

Tags: regex, bash, sed, escaping

I'm having problems with sed and the back-referencig when using variables containing regexes.
It is a parser written in bash. At a very earlier point, I want to use sed to clean every line into the needed data: the indentation, a key and a value (colon separated). The data is similar to yaml but using an equals.
A basic example of the data:

```
overview = peparing 2016-10-22
  license= sorted 2015-11-01
```

The function I'm having problems with does the logic in a while loop:

```
function prepare_parsing () {
  local file=$1

  # regex components:
  local s='[[:space:]]*'  \
        w='[a-zA-Z0-9_]*' \
        fs=':'

  # regexes(NoQuotes, SingleQuotes, DoubleQuotes):
  local searchNQ='^('$s')('$w')'$s'='$s'(.*)'$s'$'      \
        searchSQ='^('$s')('$w')'$s'='$s\''(.*)'\'$s'\$' \
        searchDQ='^('$s')('$w')'$s'='$s'"(.*)"'$s'\$'   \
        replace="\1$fs\2$fs\3"

  while IFS="$fs" read -r indentation key value; do
    ...
    SOME CUSTOM LOGIC
    ...
  done < <(sed -n "s/${searchNQ}/${replace}/p" $file)
}
```

When trying to call the function, I receive the known invalid reference error into \3:  `invalid reference \3 on s' command's RHS`

To debug this, after the vars definition, I've printed their values using the printf and the %q option.

```
printf "%q\n" $searchNQ $searchSQ $searchDQ $replace
```

Getting these values:

```
\^\(\[\[:space:\]\]\*\)\(\[a-zA-Z0-9_\]\*\)\[\[:space:\]\]\*=\[\[:space:\]\]\*\(.\*\)\[\[:space:\]\]\*\$
\^\(\[\[:space:\]\]\*\)\(\[a-zA-Z0-9_\]\*\)\[\[:space:\]\]\*=\[\[:space:\]\]\*\'\(.\*\)\'\[\[:space:\]\]\*\\\$
\^\(\[\[:space:\]\]\*\)\(\[a-zA-Z0-9_\]\*\)\[\[:space:\]\]\*=\[\[:space:\]\]\*\"\(.\*\)\"\[\[:space:\]\]\*\\\$
$'\\1\034\\2\034\\3'
```

And maybe here's the problem, the excessive escape sequences when the shell (bash) expand the variables (for example, it seems to be escaping the *, the [], ...).

If I pass the -r option to sed, it works perfectly, but I have to avoid this since the system that will execute the script won't have this sed implementation: I have to use basic sed.

Do you have any idea on how to store the regex into variables and make them usable for the backreferencing on the RHS?

It works in these two cases:

When using a plain regex string:

```
sed -n "s/^\([[:space:]]*\)\([a-zA-Z0-9_]*\)[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*\(.*\)[[:space:]]*\$/\1:\2:\3/p" $file
```

And when I use just the vars s, w and fs:

```
sed -n "s/^\($s\)\($w\)$s=$s\(.*\)$s\$/\1$fs\2$fs\3/p" $file
```

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: change `$something` to `"$something"`... (for `$s`, `$w` etc...)

Comment: I've tried already this and does not solve the problem (between single quotes the non-interpolation chars, and between double the interpolation ones: searchNQ='^('"$s"')('"$w"')'"$s"':'"$s"'(.*)'"$s"'$'
So no need to double quote (also, there is no space inside that vars).

Comment: just to confirm, you **do** have a static string version of your `sed` cmd that works? Can you include that in the question? Good luck.

Comment: Hi shelter, just added. Thanks!

Comment: It's weird that it's only the `\3` part that is blowing up.But I don't do enough sed anymore to feel I'd be successful debugging this (and the time spent). Does the `perl` version below work? If you really need the `${replaceNQ}` feature to your code, that might save you a lot of time going with that. Oh yeah, edit your question to include output of `uname -a` and `sed --version`. It may work in other environments, and then it might be classified as a bug. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

perl that supports extended RegExps may be used instead of sed, like

```
perl -n -e "s/${searchNQ}/${replace}/; print"
```